# Dynamics CRM 2016 Administration URL

Tags: crm, microsoft-dynamics, administration

I have just installed Dynamics CRM 2016 on premise.

What is the URL to get to the administration login?

Apologies for such a numpty question. I expected to get marked down just for asking :)

Comment: What do you mean when you say "Administration Login" ? are you expecting something similar to SharePoint central Administration? if so, CRM has a "Deployment Manager" app that can be used to perform administrative tasks. Window --> Deployment Manager.

Comment: Thanks for you answer Deployment Manager was what I was looking for. I was expected a web based administration system. Thanks.